# Can I configure TortoiseHg to use a custom diff tool depending on file name extension?

Tags: diff, tortoisehg

I have certain text files that must be tracked along with code, but they can be meaningfully compared only with my custom tool, not with any general purpose diff tool. Is it possible to configure TortoiseHg to use different tools depending on file name extension?

Comment: https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension

Answer (score 1):

You can use implementing `docdiff` (in *any* TortoiseHG installation) as starting point and repeate these steps for your diff-tool

1. In `$TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc` docdiff defined as additional diff-tool

> ```
> docdiff.priority=-100
> docdiff.regkey=Software\TortoiseHg
> docdiff.regappend=\docdiff.exe
> ...
> docdiff.diffargs=$child $parent
> docdiff.diff3args=$parent1 $child $parent2 $child
> ```

2. In `$TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergePatterns.rc` in `[diff-patterns]` section for *some extensions* docdiff, defined above, assigned as diff-tool

> ```
> [diff-patterns]
> **.doc = docdiff
> **.rtf = docdiff
> **.docx = docdiff
> **.docm = docdiff
> **.ppt = docdiff
> ...
> ```

Implement it for your tool+your extension in `.hgrc` for your repository and use